# Android Jetpack Compose Navigation and passing a data class with a companion Object as an argument

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a data class with a companion object that I want to pass via currentBackStackEntry in navContoller in Jetpack Compose, like so

```
  navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("arg", item)
```

But I am getting a runtime exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of type blablabla$Companion
> is not supported for navigation arguments.

I don't care if the companion object is passed or not; possible to mark it somehow to be ignored by the navigation?  (or pass it with a companion, no problem with that either). Not looking at alternative options, such as shared view model - specifically interested to find out if this particular approach is possible or not.

Comment: Calling `set` on the `currentBackStackEntry`'s `SavedStateHandle` is never how you should be passing anything in Navigation and that error isn't related to your code in any case. Please include the full stack trace and also what you are actually trying to do.